# Twitter unavailable on ios simulator

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator

Twitter says unavailable in ios simulator next to the logo in the settings. I still logged in perfectly, but why does it say unavailable.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Who uses the iPhone simulator besides programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNAVAILABLE` you're seeing is actually a button that takes you to the Twitter app in the App Store. The App Store is not available on the simulator, so the `UNAVAILABLE` button is shown. It's not stating that logging into Twitter through the simulator's settings are unavailable.

Comment: for some reason my app gives the error "The connection to com.apple.twitter.xpc was invalidated." I thought that was the reason because I logged in perfectly. Is there any other reason because my code is fine?